# C program on Pythagorean triplets-incorrect output

Tags: c, pythagorean, triplet

I want to take every combination of numbers from 1 to 30 ,a and b and want to find out their pythagorean triplets.The limit is 30 for ALL numbers.The output starts from 14.I dont understand why.I am really sorry for any gross mistakes or format errors.I have just started C.Thanks :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    float k;
    int i,j,sum;
    for(i=1;i<=30;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=30;j++)
        {
            sum=(i*i)+(j*j);
            k=sqrt(sum);
            if(k>30.0)
            { 
                break;
            }           
            printf("Pythagorean Triplets are %d,%d,%f \n",i,j,k);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlzSf.png)

Comment: Well, what is the expected output??

Comment: And have you done any debugging?

Comment: Pythagorean triplets are supposed to be integers.

Comment: I was under the illusion that you needed to test `i*i + j*j == k*k` for integers `i`, `j`, and `k`.  You need to rethink what you're up to.  Probably, `k` should be an integer, and you calculate it somewhat similarly to how you're doing it, but worry about rounding.  Then do the check.

Comment: The program works just fine..https://ideone.com/zpBA4n

Comment: I would guess that *"The output starts from 14"* because the first results were truncated, as the output list is pretty long. Redirect it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Leffler already wrote in the comments, you need to test for the equality `i*i + j*j == k*k`.  You cannot not do it directly because `f` is a float and `i,j` are integers, you need them all to be of an integer data type. Not much of a problem, just do something in the line of

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  float k;
  int i, j, sum, k2;
  for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 30; j++) {
      sum = (i * i) + (j * j);
      // you have "float k", hence "sqrtf()" instead of "sqrt()"
      // which is for "double"s
      k = sqrtf(sum);
      // floating point numbers with any notes are "double"s,
      // hence the "F" at the end
      if (k > 30.0F) {
        break;
      }
      // this may not work for very large values but you have 30
      // as your upper limit which is low enough
      k2 = (int) floorf(k);
      if (k2 * k2 == sum) {
        // use 2 digits for the format, makes it a bit more readable
        printf("Pythagorean Triplets are %2d, %2d, %2d\n", i, j, k2);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The otherwise obligatory error checks can be omitted here, because the input is known and more so known to be always valid.

But the list is still bigger than expected, it contains doublets, e.g.: `3, 4, 5` and `4, 3, 5` but I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: No, one cannot really use `floor` here if the sqrtf happens to be numerically unstable. Better to use `round`. There has been several problems caused by `floor(pow(10, 2))` equalling 99 on some implementations, so ...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala as you already hinted at, that is an implementation related problem. There are several stable implementations of `sqrtf()` available, you can use one of those instead if your LibC does not offer one..

Comment: However there is still no good reason to use `floor` instead of `round`. The closest integer is the one to try.